# How to break the data in rdlc after grouping?

Tags: c#-3.0

I am working with RDLC Report in VS 2010.while Displaying the Report after Grouping the table by CustomerName in rdlc ,I am getting the output as mentioned below:

Page 1

```
           CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount 

              Narmadha     6         250.00

                           61        550.00

                           62        1250.00

                           63        2500.00


           CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount 

               Soorya          16        1250.00

                               21        560.00
```

Page 2

```
           CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount

             Soorya           26        2150.00

                             163       500.00
```

upto N Records

But I need the output in the following format:

Page 1

```
            CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount 

              Narmadha        6         250.00

                              61        550.00

                              62        1250.00

                              63        2500.00
```

--------------Page Break--------------

```
            CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount 

              Soorya          16        1250.00

                              21        560.00

                              26        2150.00

                             163       500.00
```

upto N Records

I want to break the Grouping data , even i tried to break the rows by the expression,Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/4).I got the output as mentioned above.But the problem i faced is that,if suppose 'soorya' has only three invoices means,i am getting the output  as

```
               CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount 

                  Narmadha        6         250.00

                                 61        550.00

                                 62        1250.00

                                 63        2500.00
```

--------------Page Break--------------

```
                CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount 

                 Soorya          16        1250.00

                                 21        560.00

                                 26        2150.00

                 ranjana         163       500.00
```

--------------Page Break--------------

```
              CustomerName   Invoice  InvoiceAmount 

               ranjana         16        1250.00

                               21        560.00

                               26        2150.00

                               32        1500.00
```

upto N records

can any one help me?

Comment: @user285008 Improve accept-rate. Don't need to introduce yourself in the question, just update your profile. Avoid heavy usage of ellipses... specially, when not required. :) And you just undid my edit, ruined the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

groupproperties

> > Pagebreaks
> >     on chceckbox of break page between each instance